# Adding multiple line at the end of the file using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting, powershell-core

I am trying to add multiple line at the end of the file using powershell.
for example : The file is already present and have some content in it.

```
abc.txt

abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
```

So abc.txt file looks like something I have mention above.
Now i am trying to add below content at the end of the file and on new line.

```
qwe
asd
zxc
vbn
```

The final output will be - abc.txt

```
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
qwe
asd
zxc
vbn
```

As i am a newbiw i tried adding one line in a file which has been perform successfully but no idea of adding multiple line.

```
 Add-Content "./sample3.txt" "This is the last line `n"
```

Comment: Try with `Out-File -Append -NoNewLine` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Might also be possible that a new line was already there on your file hence why when you add content to your file you see an empty line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add content as given below. [Read more on here string](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/)

```
$contentToAdd = @"
qwe
asd
zxc
vbn
"@

 Add-Content "C:\dev\abc.txt" $contentToAdd
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.The script works perfect but the content get add to leaving one line for eg: if file content end at 29 line then after running the script it adds the content from 31 line . There is a gap of one line.Is there any solution for it.Thanks once again for helping.

Comment: When you put the here string, after "@, put an Enter to insert a new line and keep the content. I tested it. It worked fine for me.